# python regular expression also match special characters

Tags: python, regex

currently I use this simple script to search for a tag in the string;

```
tag = "#tag"
text = "test string with #tag inserted"
match = re.search(tag, text, re.IGNORECASE) #matches
```

now suppose the text contains an a-acute;

```
tag = "#tag"
text = "test string with #tág inserted"
match = re.search(tag, text, re.IGNORECASE) #does not match :(
```

How do I make this match work? should work for other special chars too (é, è, í, etc..)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do "other special chars" include things like ∆ or Ж or 新 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can normalize the text with [unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode):

```
import unicodedata

tag = "#tag"
text = u"test string with #tág inserted and a #tag"
text=unidecode(text)
re.findall(tag, text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

**out:**

```
['#tag', '#tag']
```

Comment: `unidecode` is not a standard Python library. Could you post a link?

Comment: This doesn't account for the possibility that `'tag'` itself might be in the string though.

Comment: @Volatility -- i am not sure i follow, can you elaborate.

Comment: hmm, now that I read over the question... I thought the OP wanted to find all `'#tág'`s and not `'#tag'` - obviously I misread, sorry ;)